# Tkinter not working on Debian 12 Bookworm, Python 3.11.5

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, debian, python-3.11

As the title states, I can't get tkinter code running. I get the error:

> No module named '_tkinter'

> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

I'm running Debian 12 Bookwork, and Python 3.11.5, and after trying the suggestions on this site like:
`sudo apt-get install python3-tk` or `sudo apt-get install python3.11-tk` it tells me that python3-tk is already the newest version.

I've gone so far as to create a droplet on digital ocean for debian 12, and it had python 3.11.2 installed, but I was able to add the package and run the import statement.

Did I break or misconfigure my python installation somehow? If so, is there some way to fix it short of wiping and reinstalling the OS?

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:
I've reduced the code to just this and getting the errors above:
`import tkinter as tk`

At first I was using an virtual environment via `python3 -m venv venv` but to simplify things I'm just trying to run the above import statement in the terminal with `python3 tk_test.py`

results of commands from comments:

`which python3` -> `/usr/local/bin/python3`

`ls /usr/lib/python*/lib-dynload/_tkinter.*` -> `/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-311d-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

EDIT: closing this question as i've fixed it by compiling python 3.11.8 from source. I can only assume I broke my python install at some point. I used these steps to compile and replace my installation with python 3.11.8: https://fostips.com/install-python-3-10-debian-11/

Comment: Are you calling `import tkinter` or `import _tkinter`?

Comment: Which code editor are you using?

Comment: I think the simple answer is that when you run your script you're using a different version of python than the ones that have tkinter installed.

Comment: @BryanOakley is there an easy way to tell at runtime which version of python is running and which parts of the standard library it has access to?

Comment: What's the output of `which python3`? Is it `/usr/bin/python3`? How about the output of `ls /usr/lib/python*/lib-dynload/_tkinter.*`?

Comment: The *latest stable* Python version in my debian 12 is 3.11.2, but yours is 3.11.5.  Did you compile the Python from source?

Comment: Could also check the output of `python3 -m site`

Comment: @acw1668 i don't recall doing that, but i'm not a linux expert and i have been messing around with different virtual environments and different python versions. is there an easy way to revert to a stable version of 3.11.2 without bricking my OS?

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/python3 -m tkinter` successfully?

Comment: You need to refresh on SD CARD and try start all over again. So you can get back Python 3.11.2. There is new Bookworm Update Release date: December 5th 2023.

Comment: OK, that must be it. If you're compiling Python from source, you shouldn't be installing libraries with apt. Libraries installed with apt are intended to work with the programs installed with apt.